# Excel SumIF with range as Column and Sum range as ROW

Tags: excel, sum

I am trying to make this work:

```
=SUMIF(MATRIX!$B$2:$B$36,"YES",B5:AJ5)
```

Note that the range is a `COLUMN` and the sum range is a `ROW` but when the formula computes it doesn't sum the Row `B5:AJ5` it actually sums `B5:B40`.   What do I need to add to have it sum the `ROW` and not the `COLUMN`.

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, a SUMIF expects both the criteria array and the sum array to be both rows or columns but not one of each. You have correctly used the same number of cells in each; the problem is that they are in different directions. A TRANSPOSE function can reverse the direction that the outer function 'sees' the one of the arrays but you need to change from SUMIF to SUMPRODUCT and enter it as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$5="yes")*(TRANSPOSE($H2:$K2)))
```

When entered correctly with CSE, the result in L2 is `2.3`. Fill both right and down for something resembling the following.

[image]

I don't believe you can use transpose with SUMIF but someone might know a trick to it.